# What jinja2 template features are available in Aggregation Formats?

Tags: getstream-io

The documentation says aggregation rules use Jinja2 template syntax (https://getstream.io/docs/#aggregated-feeds), however many Jinja2 features don't seem to be supported and return syntax errors when trying to preview on the getstream.io aggregated feed group config screen.

For example, `{{ actor|replace(":", "|") }}` and `{{ actor|length }}` return syntax errors, but `{{ actor|lower }}` and `{{ actor|int }}` seem to work fine.

Does anyone know what subset of Jinja2 features are actually supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use a very limited set of filters. For example `int`, `lower` and `strftime` on the time object. Next to that you can use the `if`, `else` and `endif` control structures.

We're working on a complete list and will document them here: https://getstream.io/docs/#aggregated-feeds and update this SO answer accordingly.

We hope this satisfies your needs for now.